# How to create a relationship with lambda in rails 4.0.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements, relationship

I have a model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :collaborated_projects, :through => :collaborations, :source => :project
end
```

and another model Collaboration

```
class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :collaboratable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :project,
  :foreign_key => 'collaboratable_id',
  :conditions => {"collaborations.collaboratable_type" => 'Project'}

end
```

As the relationship suggests User can have multiple collaborated projects.

The above code is running fine but throwing an error

`DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Collaboration.belongs_to :project declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:`

I tried

```
belongs_to :project,
:foreign_key => 'collaboratable_id',
-> { where("collaborations.collaboratable_type" => 'Project')}
```

but it throws an error

```
SyntaxError: /....app/models/collaboration.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4, the lambda scope `-> { ... }` needs to be defined before any other options.  So, try:

```
belongs_to :project,
-> { where("collaborations.collaboratable_type = 'Project'")}, 
:foreign_key => 'collaboratable_id'
```